# Magento 2.3.5 - API error The "array" class doesn't exist and the namespace must be specified

Tags: magento2.3, api, rest-api, soap-api-v2, magento2.3.5

We get the following API error on our Magento 2.3.5 store;

```
The "array" class doesn't exist and the namespace must be specified. Verify and try again.
```

More info;

```
<![CDATA[#0 /vendor/magento/module-webapi/Model/Config/ClassReflector.php(103): Magento\Framework\Reflection\TypeProcessor->register('array') #1 /vendor/magento/module-webapi/Model/Config/ClassReflector.php(72): Magento\Webapi\Model\Config\ClassReflector->extractMethodData(Object(Laminas\Code\Reflection\MethodReflection)) #2 /vendor/magento/module-webapi/Model/ServiceMetadata.php(133): Magento\Webapi\Model\Config\ClassReflector->reflectClassMethods('Mollie\\Payment\\...', Array) #3 /vendor/magento/module-webapi/Model/ServiceMetadata.php(166): Magento\Webapi\Model\ServiceMetadata->initServicesMetadata() #4 /vendor/magento/module-webapi/Model/ServiceMetadata.php(189): Magento\Webapi\Model\ServiceMetadata->getServicesConfig() #5 /vendor/magento/module-webapi/Model/Soap/Wsdl/Generator.php(367): Magento\Webapi\Model\ServiceMetadata->getServiceMetadata('iCEShopICECatCo...') #6 /vendor/magento/module-webapi/Model/AbstractSchemaGenerator.php(172): Magento\Webapi\Model\Soap\Wsdl\Generator->getServiceMetadata('iCEShopICECatCo...') #7 /vendor/magento/module-webapi/Model/Soap/Wsdl/Generator.php(375): Magento\Webapi\Model\AbstractSchemaGenerator->getAllowedServicesMetadata(Array) #8 /vendor/magento/module-webapi/Model/AbstractSchemaGenerator.php(107): Magento\Webapi\Model\Soap\Wsdl\Generator->getAllowedServicesMetadata(Array) #9 /vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Soap.php(134): Magento\Webapi\Model\AbstractSchemaGenerator->generate(Array, 'https', 'domain.com', 'domain.com'') #10 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Soap->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) #11 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Soap\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array) #12 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Soap\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) #13 /generated/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Soap/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Soap\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array) #14 /vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Soap\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) #15 /vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(261): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() #16 /pub/index.php(40): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http)) #17 {main}]]>
```

Comment: did you tried removing var/cache, view_processed, generated, and then run di:compile, upgrade, and deploy

Comment: @Chikku Thanks! Yes we did remove the things, but it seems that the error also occurs on developer mode.

Comment: do you have this line in your code @return array ?

Comment: @Chikku Thanks, we solved the issue. Problem was caused by a third party update. Downgraded that module to the single last version and it is working fine again.

Comment: glad you make it worked.good day

Comment: @JGeer if you resolve the issue please post the answer here so it will help others

Comment: @NirajPatel Thanks, the issue was caused by a third party module. We downgraded that module to the previous version and that solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It might due to the `@return` type in your docblock is invalid.
Magento will throw such exception if you don't use fully qualified interface name as like this:

```
   /**
     * @return OrderInterface
     */
    public function getOrder();
```

it should be:

```
/**
 * @return \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface
 */
public function getOrder();
```

More detail:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-to-web-service.html#service-interface-requirements